# specifying javascript OO "this" object from D3 .on function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have defined a Javascript object, one of whose methods I would like to serve as a D3 .on() call function (e.g. d3.select("circle").on("mouseover", myMethod)). How could I refer to the object's "this" method instead of the DOM object's "this" method when the .on() function is triggered from within that function?

For example:

```
function Lollipop() {
  var objHack = this;
  this.lickColor = "red";   
  d3.select("circle")
  .on("mouseover", objHack.licked);
}

/* 
instead of the constant "red", 
want to use this.lickColor where "this" 
is the Lollipop "this" rather than the DOM object "this"
*/
Lollipop.prototype.licked = function() {
  d3.select(this).attr("fill", "red");
}

var l = new Lollipop();
```

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/J4aUP/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
function Lollipop() {
    var objHack = this;
    this.lickColor = "red";   
    d3.select("circle").on("mouseover", objHack.licked);
    d3.that = this;
}

Lollipop.prototype.licked = function() {
    d3.select(this).attr("fill", d3.that.lickColor);
}

var l = new Lollipop();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/J4aUP/3/

Comment: +1 I like this solution too...or should I say that solution?! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the global `d3.event` to retrieve the current event inside a listener. Then, in order to keep your class context inside an anonymous function, you can use the [bind method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

```
function Lollipop() {
    this.lickColor = "red";   
    d3.select("circle")
        .on("mouseover", this.licked.bind(this));
}

Lollipop.prototype.licked = function () {
    d3.select(d3.event.target).attr("fill", this.lickColor);
}

var l = new Lollipop();
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/J4aUP/2/)